# Facing Error at the time of saving data in data Source

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine

I am facing problem in saving data on google map engine data source.        Error : buffer  length is greater than 1 : { "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "invalid",    "message": "This value is invalid."   }  ],  "code": 400,  "message": "This value is invalid." }}

where "buffer  length is greater than 1 " is a custom message.

Feature :
     {"features":[{"properties":{"Name":"Vijay Tr","Work_Email":"vijay.tomar@lovly.com","Job_Title":"Lead r","Reporting_Location":"Ind ","Total_Experience":9,"Mobile_Phone":"9313432451","Department":"LINT","gx_id":"","Reporting_To":"Ashish Gupta"},"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.02190399169922,28.455472946166992]}}]}

Feature is a Valid Json.

```
 try {
        mapDataURL = new URL(url);
        if (mapDataURL != null) {
            urlConnection = mapDataURL.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(600000);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");


            String gmeToken = saa.getOAuthTokenForMapsEngine();
            if (gmeToken != null && gmeToken.length() > 0) {
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + gmeToken);
            }

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());


            JSONArray latLngAry = new JSONArray();
            latLngAry.put(Float.parseFloat(lng));
            latLngAry.put(Float.parseFloat(lat));

        JSONObject geometry=new JSONObject();
            geometry.put("type","Point");
            geometry.put("coordinates",latLngAry);

        JSONObject jsonProperties=new JSONObject();
            jsonProperties.put("Name",name.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Job_Title",jobTitle.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Reporting_To",reportingTo.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Department",department.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Work_Email",email.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Mobile_Phone",mobilePhone.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Reporting_Location",reportingLocation.trim());
            jsonProperties.put("Total_Experience",Float.parseFloat(experience.trim()));
            jsonProperties.put("gx_id", "" + gx_id + "");

        JSONObject jsonFeature=new JSONObject();
            jsonFeature.put("properties", jsonProperties);  
            jsonFeature.put("type", "Feature");
            jsonFeature.put("geometry", geometry);

        String jsonStr = "{\"features\":[" + jsonFeature  + "]}";
        log.info("jsonStr : "+jsonStr); 

        wr.write(jsonStr);
            log.info(" writing String Success : "+wr.toString());
            wr.flush();
             log.info("Url : "+mapDataURL);
            // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();

        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        buffer = new StringBuffer("MalformedURLException : "+ e.getMessage() );


    } catch (IOException e) {
        buffer = new StringBuffer("IOException : " +e.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        buffer = new StringBuffer("Generic Exception : "+e.getMessage());

    } finally {

    if (buffer.length() < 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        log.info("buffer  length is greater than 1 : "+buffer.toString());
        return false;
    } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to return `true` here? With `buffer.length() < 1`, any value that is greater than an empty buffer will cause it to return `false`. So, if `buffer.append(line)` is expected to be called, you will always return `false`.

I suggest changing the `buffer.length() < 1` condition.